# Duplicate Multiple files are downloading with single XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, browser, download, xmlhttprequest

Hi with below XMLHttpRequest implementation, Multiple duplicate files are getting downloaded with a single request. Is there any way to avoid this.

`var location = abc+ "/tasksample/"; var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); window.location.assign(location ); xhr.open("GET", location , true); xhr.send();`